# Scala covariant container

Tags: scala, covariance

I came across an example from a Scala cookbook. I understood the example and I made some changes to make sure I understood the example thoroughly.

The code example,

```
trait Animal {
    def speak
}

class Dog(var name: String) extends Animal {
    def speak { println("Dog says woof") }
}

class SuperDog(name: String) extends Dog(name) {
     override def speak { println("I'm a SuperDog") }
} 

// solution 1
class Container[+T](val elem : T) 

def makeDogsSpeak(dogHouse: Container[Dog]) {
    dogHouse.elem.speak
}

val superDogHouse = new Container(new SuperDog("Wonder Dog")) 
makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse)
```

---

```
// solution 2
class Container[T](val elem : T)  // remove covariant from type 

def makeDogsSpeak[U <: Dog](dogHouse: Container[U]) {
    dogHouse.elem.speak
}

val superDogHouse = new Container(new SuperDog("Wonder Dog"))
makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse)
```

1. Are there any advantages of solution 1 over solution 2? Or it is a
   matter of preference?
2. For solution 1, I modified the code to,

.

```
class Container[T](val elem : T) // remove covariant from type       
val superDogHouse = new Container(new SuperDog("Wonder Dog")) 
makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse) // compilation error
```

BUT if I do this,

```
makeDogsSpeak(new Container(new SuperDog("Wonder Dog"))) // superDogHouse removed
```

the compiler compiled. What was happening here? Was it not the "same" code? Thanks

Comment: Hm, could it be that in the second case, there is a different type inferred? Could it be a bug in Scala?

Comment: Please add the error message you got.

Comment: I could reproduce this behaviour with Scala 2.10.3. The error message looks like this: 

`scala> makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse)

<console>:14: error: type mismatch;

 found   : Container[SuperDog]

 required: Container[Dog]

Note: SuperDog <: Dog, but class Container is invariant in type T.

You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)

              makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse)
                            ^`

Which makes perfect sense to me, but then it's strange that in the second case compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About variance declaration (**question 1**):

Declaration-side variance:

```
class Container[+T](val elem : T)
```

Using-side variance:

```
def makeDogsSpeak(dogHouse: Container[_ <: Dog])
```

Using of declaration- or using-side variance notation dependent of your code design. In some cases method can be generic (and type inference for short notation can be used) but in some cases method can not be generic.

For some classes covarince of parameter is only one way to good design. for example:

```
trait List[+A]
object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

using:

```
val xs : List[Int] = Nil // will not possible in case List[A]
```

Also for some cases mix of declaration & using side varince needed, because position of parameters in container are related to variance.

Covariant position parameter:

```
trait C[+T] {
  def get : T
}
```

Contravariant position:

```
trait C[-T] {
  def set(x : T): Unit
}
```

but not:

```
trait C[+T] {
  def get : T 
  def set(x : T): Unit // wrong position of type T
}
```

Fix by mixing declaration- & using-side variance:

```
trait C[+T] {
  def get : T 
  def set[TT >: T](x : TT): Unit // ok
}
```

About **question 2**:

taking to account rules of type inference, for compiler your code look like:

```
val superDogHouse = new Container[SuperDog](new SuperDog("Wonder Dog")) 
makeDogsSpeak(superDogHouse) // compilation error
```

and

```
makeDogsSpeak(new Container[Dog](new SuperDog("Wonder Dog")))
```

And reason why it is worked in first case and did not worken in second is a type of container.

Comment: The question is why is the type inference different in these two cases? Shouldn't it be idempotent?

Comment: @Ashalynd no. In the first case the compiler infers the type of the container from the type of its argument (which is `SuperDog`). In the second case it infers the type of the container from the type of its argument (which is still `SuperDog`) *and* the type of the function it is being passed to (which requires a `Container[Dog]`). This is not done in the first case because the type inference engine doesn't look ahead.